# Why is my Column Data is Off by One in Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm using the Pandas library to work with text because I find it *far* easier than the `csv` module.  Here's the problem.  I have a .csv file with multiple columns: `subtitle`, `title,` and `description`.  Here's how I access the row content within each column.

```
colnames = ['subtitle', 'description', 'title']
data = pandas.read_csv('C:\Users\B\cwitems.csv', names=colnames)
subtit = list(data.subtitle)
desc = list(data.description)
title = list(data.title)

for line in zip(subtit, desc, title):
    print line
```

The issue is that, for whatever reason, when I print `line`, the expected subtitle isn't printed.  When I print each `desc`, the title shows up.  And when I print `subtit` by itself, the description is printed.  Thus, it appears that each column is off by -1.  Can anyone explain this behavior?  Is it expected and how do I avoid it?

Comment: Do you have an index in your csv? if not then try this `data = pandas.read_csv('C:\Users\B\cwitems.csv', names=colnames, index_col=None)`

Comment: Hmm. the default should be `None` for the index_col anyway. Can you post the first few lines of your csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were trying to load a file with 4 columns but only gave 3 col names. If you only need to load the first 3 columns, use

```
data = pandas.read_csv('C:\Users\B\cwitems.csv', names=colnames, usecols=[0,1,2])
```

You don't have to delete the unused column in the file.

By default, read_csv loads all columns, and in your case #cols = #colnames+1, so the first column is used as dataframe index. All the remaining columns are shifted by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an answer, But it was too long for the comment. Feel free to ignore it.

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> 
>>> l1 = [1,2]
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l3 = [1,2,3]
>>> 
>>> for line in izip_longest(l1,l2,l3):
...     print line
```

will print :

```
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
(None, 3, 3)
(None, 4, None)
(None, 5, None)
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be the answer, it is to do with the format of the csv and the default behaviour of pandas when reading the csv

Comment: If you want me to remove it, so I wan't stop other people from looking at the question, let me know

Comment: I wouldn't suggest removing it yet, I have quite a bit of experience with pandas which is why I made the comment, I need to see the csv data before I can establish the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have added `index_col=False` for `pd.read_csv`, it's OK right now.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I solved the problem - tho I didn't find this anywhere in the docs, so perhaps a more experienced Pandas users can explain why/how.  I certainly cannot.

Here's what I did:  I deleted an unused column (the last column in my .csv file), and that reset the indices to their proper/expected order.  I have no idea what explains the behavior (or its correction) - whether it's related to my .csv file or whether it's a Pandas thing (and perhaps only a Pandas' issue when working with text).  I don't know.

Either way, I really appreciate all of help!!  I got lucky this time.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, turns out the .csv I was trying to download had no comma at the end of the header row, but did have commas at the end of every other row. Passing index_col=False (not index_col=None, the default) forces pandas to create an index column instead of inferring one, which got my data to line up correctly.